# Query in json in postgres with multiple values

Tags: json, postgresql

I have json stored `[1,2,4,5]`.I have array s like `[1,23,4]`. I want to check either value of s array exist in json fields. Other options I may need to store array like `['1','2','4','5']` so i can use`?|` operator or their is anything else i can do ?

Comment: can you add the table structure, sample data and expected output to understand better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ready-to-use function or operator to accomplish that. You can use the function:

```
create or replace function jsonb_int_array(jsonb)
returns integer[] language sql immutable as $function$
    select array(select jsonb_array_elements_text($1)::int)
$function$;
```

In the query use the [overlap operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html):

```
with my_table(data) as (
values ('[1,2,4,5]'::jsonb)
)

select *
from my_table
where jsonb_int_array(data) && array[1,23,4]

     data     
--------------
 [1, 2, 4, 5]
(1 row)
```